# Rider warning on Unity project due to incorrect namespace

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

Rider is showing a warning on all my C# scripts because they do not have "GameName.Scripts" in the beggining of their namespace.

Rider offers a [checkbox on a folder's property to prevent them to be namespace providers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html). Unchecking this checkbox in the folder Scripts and GameName solves my problem but it creates one `.DotSettings` file for each asmdef in my project (in my case there are 52 new files).

Is there any other way to solve this without having to create so many files?

Comment: Not familiar with the details of Unity project, but I assume you have single solution (`.sln`) file. Resharper has project-wide and solution-wide settings, so you can create `SolutionName.sln.DotSettings` and put the settings there.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to **Settings | Editor | Inspection Settings | Inspection Severity | C#** and disable the `Namespace does not correspond to file location` inspection. Consider saving this setting only for the current project by opening the drop-down menu for the Save button and selecting **Solution personal** or **Solution team-shared** layer.